# Clarifai api referenceerror : process is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, npm, clarifai

I get such an error on npm start on clarifai api
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHRNz.png

Open bootstrap:27:

```
    // Execute the module function
    try {
        var execOptions = { id: moduleId, module: module, factory: __webpack_modules__[moduleId], require: __webpack_require__ };
        __webpack_require__.i.forEach(function(handler) { handler(execOptions); });
        module = execOptions.module;
        execOptions.factory.call(module.exports, module, module.exports, execOptions.require);
    } catch(e) {
        module.error = e;
        throw e;
    }

    // Flag the module as loaded
    module.loaded = true;

    // Return the exports of the module
    return module.exports;
}
```

and my App.js details;

```
const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '****',
})
 
///

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    console.log('click')
    app.models
      .predict(
        '45fb9a671625463fa646c3523a3087d5',
        'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg'
      )
      .then(
        function (response) {
          console.log(response)
        },
        function (err) {
          //
        }
      )
  }
```

I am getting this error before render in console.log. what would be the reason?

Happy coding day! :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript#basic-use) you need to use [Broserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage). You are missing NodeJS globals. Please let us know if this does not work for you as this library is unfortunately not under active maintenance currently.

Comment: @zanthez how did you fix the problem?

Comment: @JOHNEDWARDBINAY I just remember that it was due to the conflict of the wrong versions